# CSS3 transition with jQuery .addClass and .removeClass is not working when scroll down

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

I need something like when user scroll down 20px then the manu bar should be sticky with an animated transition way.But in this case the css animation is not working.If you have any solution let me know..Thanks in advance.

Jquery:

```js
jQuery(window).scroll(function()
    {
        if( jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 30 )
        {
            jQuery('.dark-menu').addClass('navbar-fixed-top').animate({transition: ".2s all"});
        } 
        else 
        {
            jQuery('.dark-menu').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
        }
    });
```

```css
.top-header {
    text-align:center;
    background:#f9f9f9;
    padding:6px;
}
.dark-menu {
    text-align:center;
    background:#444;
    color:#fff;
    padding:20px;
}
ul li {
    list-style:none;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 10px;
}
.navbar-fixed-top {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    -webkit-transition: .3s all;
    -moz-transition: ;
    -ms-transition: ;
    -o-transition: ;
    transition: ;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
    <div class="top-header">
        <p>My Phone Number</p>
    </div>
    <nav class="dark-menu">
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Logo</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
            <li>Examples</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
<article>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut eveniet rem, tempora aut numquam asperiores consequatur deleniti architecto minus modi vel ipsa optio perspiciatis saepe quas fugit dignissimos non ipsum eos magnam tenetur eius quae, temporibus in. Blanditiis, voluptates! Reprehenderit autem enim et voluptatum nostrum reiciendis repellat temporibus laborum accusamus, ad. Reprehenderit corporis sapiente ducimus enim quisquam aspernatur, deserunt ab impedit accusamus magni sed dolor est pariatur vero, tempore possimus itaque rem aut adipisci cupiditate cum. Unde perspiciatis consequatur nam corporis ipsam eaque asperiores eligendi, autem cum, quia ea sequi, a. Accusantium dolor sit commodi corporis quis, possimus quibusdam iure eaque delectus porro, consequatur, earum quo voluptates maxime voluptas beatae nostrum atque voluptate ipsum fugit! Architecto debitis obcaecati laborum. Architecto quos cumque adipisci placeat, nisi sequi, praesentium aperiam. Nam culpa tempora quibusdam autem, consectetur sequi repellat corporis modi magni numquam aliquid reprehenderit in vel fugit! Quisquam explicabo repellendus sunt animi tempora accusantium fugiat dignissimos asperiores molestias, veritatis laboriosam. Nobis tempore, eius saepe velit alias ullam possimus tempora rerum omnis dignissimos pariatur quod vitae, perspiciatis quas corporis at laborum. Explicabo possimus recusandae quas sint voluptatibus perspiciatis quisquam consectetur nisi consequuntur rerum illo maiores asperiores incidunt dignissimos, facere excepturi, labore nemo adipisci dolorum, veniam deserunt quae! Qui ratione impedit inventore, itaque quasi porro fugit voluptas ducimus unde. Dicta, temporibus iste, fugit aspernatur sunt veniam deleniti corrupti maxime voluptates cumque quos possimus ipsa dignissimos consequuntur quasi, pariatur dolorem dolores aliquid. Quidem repellendus explicabo, repellat voluptates voluptatibus iste doloremque adipisci impedit distinctio ipsa eveniet labore, repudiandae qui praesentium dolor, beatae reiciendis error cupiditate? Vitae eius reprehenderit illo ratione, autem, ipsam eaque, distinctio cupiditate suscipit architecto ab dolores rerum cumque praesentium harum dolorem aperiam nisi error! Facere pariatur repudiandae natus fugit optio, porro quas nihil placeat tenetur. Nostrum, repudiandae, doloremque. Doloribus adipisci, provident et aliquid totam eligendi earum, assumenda perspiciatis quasi a quidem, aliquam molestiae quaerat! At facilis amet nulla nisi nihil mollitia culpa eius magni quam qui distinctio, sed delectus vitae magnam. Velit eos, accusantium similique! Maiores, harum iusto ipsum recusandae facilis. Impedit architecto illo facere porro. Obcaecati eligendi perferendis fugit, quis accusamus numquam. Architecto ex, expedita asperiores aperiam dolore cumque accusantium beatae fuga dolor ducimus! Repellendus perspiciatis nemo est quidem cumque aspernatur rem sed perferendis reprehenderit veniam ipsam quibusdam ea voluptatum doloremque animi, officia ex, autem quis voluptates deleniti in laboriosam iusto. Numquam vero voluptatibus, eos libero praesentium ipsum sint, explicabo eum sequi!</p>
</article>
```

Comment: Anything like this you were after (looks a bit odd with smoothscroll Firefox though)? http://tinyurl.com/naonf82

Answer (score 0):

Add top attribute in `.dark-menu` class

```
.dark-menu {
    top:50px; /*or any other value you want*/
    text-align:center;
    background:#444;
    color:#fff;
    padding:20px;
}
```

Comment: Let me check.But I need some transition animation

Comment: Did it work? And the css transition you've added in .navbar-fixed-top class will work fine!

Comment: No Luck For me @Malika